mongoose findAndUpdate with discriminator
I have several types of products such as phones, laptops, headphones, etc. All of these products in the end result turns out to be you one generalized ProductsModel
ProductsModel
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

export const productsDiscriminatorKey = 'productKind'

const ProductsSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
    },
    { productsDiscriminatorKey, timestamps: true }
)

export default model('Products', ProductsSchema)


PhoneModel
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

import ProductsModel, { productsDiscriminatorKey } from './ProductsModel.js'

const PhoneSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: String, required: true },
        color: { type: String, required: true },
        memory: { type: String, required: true },
        screen: { type: String, required: true },
        fps: { type: String, required: true },
        sim: { type: String, required: true },
        preview: { type: String, required: true },
        images: [{ type: String, required: true }],
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
        },
        type: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Type',
        },
        count: { type: Number },
    },
    { productsDiscriminatorKey }
)

const PhoneModel = ProductsModel.discriminator('Phones', PhoneSchema)
export default PhoneModel


I implemented the logic of removing products from the database by quantity, rather than the entire model at once. If I use it specifically in the PhoneModel or in another model (not in the ProductsModel), then all the logic works correctly. But as soon as I try to do this from ProductsModel, then it just doesn't change the count field.
Delete logic
    async delete(req, res) {
        try {
            const { id } = req.params
            const { count } = req.body

            const candidate = await ProductsModel.findById(id)

            if (candidate.count < count) {
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'More than count in base' })
            }

            if (candidate.count === count || !count) {
                await ProductsModel.findByIdAndDelete(id)
                return res.status(200).json({ message: 'All deleted' })
            }

            if (candidate.count > count) {
                await ProductsModel.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { count: candidate.count - count })

                return res.status(200).json({ message: `${count} successfully deleted` })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' })
        }
    }

That is, there is a case when you need to delete not all at once, but a certain amount (count). I implemented this by simply changing the count field using findByIdAndUpdate. But it just doesn't work out and doesn't throw out any errors.

It does not work since the base schema does not have access to the keys in an inherited schema.
In the below statement of this case, the base schema is trying to access the key count in the inherited schema. ProductsModel and PhoneModel are the base and inherited schemas respectively. The key count belongs to the inherited schema PhoneModel. It does not belong to the base schema ProductsModel. Therefore mongoose will ignore this update document { count: candidate.count - count }.
await ProductsModel.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { count: candidate.count - count })

However the following queries will work correctly since the key _id is existing in both schemas.
const candidate = await ProductsModel.findById(id)
await ProductsModel.findByIdAndDelete(id)

The following code demonstrates the same. Please take note of the lines - line 1, line 2 and line 3. In all these lines, the given assertion passes since the base schema does not have access to the keys in an inherited schema.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const asserts = require('assert');

const options = { discriminatorKey: 'kind' };

const parentSchema = new Schema({ parentkey1: String }, options);
const Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);

const childSchema = new Schema({ childkey1: String }, options);
const Child = Parent.discriminator('Child', childSchema, options);

let parentdoc = new Parent({
  parentkey1: 'parentkey1',
});

let childdoc = new Child({
  parentkey1: 'parentkey1',
  childkey1: 'childkey1',
});

// document objects
asserts.ok(parentdoc._id);
asserts.ok(childdoc._id);

asserts.ok(parentdoc.parentkey1);
asserts.ok(!parentdoc.childkey1);  // line 1
asserts.ok(childdoc.parentkey1);
asserts.ok(childdoc.childkey1);

run().catch((err) => console.log(err));
async function run() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');
  await Parent.deleteMany();
  await Child.deleteMany();
  await parentdoc.save();
  await childdoc.save();

  parentdoc = await Parent.findById(parentdoc._id);
  childdoc = await Child.findById(childdoc._id);

  asserts.ok(parentdoc._id);
  asserts.ok(childdoc._id);

  asserts.ok(parentdoc.parentkey1);
  asserts.ok(!parentdoc.childkey1); // line 2
  asserts.ok(childdoc.parentkey1);
  asserts.ok(childdoc.childkey1);

  parentdoc = await Parent.findByIdAndUpdate(parentdoc._id, {
    childkey1: 'new value',
  });
  asserts.ok(parentdoc.parentkey1);
  asserts.ok(!parentdoc.childkey1);  // line 3
}

